# jquery ui datepicker - get siblings of input on beforeShow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery's datepicker and I'm trying to set an array on beforeShow based on the values in a sibling select element.

Here's what I've tried, but it's neither working or throwing any errors.

```
beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
    $(input).siblings("select.startdates").find("option").each( function() {
        startDates.push($(this).val())
    });
    console.log($(input).siblings("select.startdates"))
},
```

The log returns `[]`

The html looks something like this:

```
<input class="hasDatepicker" id="myInput" />
<div>
<select class="startDates">
    <option value="2013, 2, 1">01/03/2013</option>
    ....
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `$(input).siblings("select.startdates")` and `$(input).siblings("select.startdates").find('option')` return the elements that you are after? Log them in the console.

Comment: `console.log($(input).siblings("select.startdates"))` returns an empty array, which is strange

Comment: Please post the relevant html structure

Comment: That was bad copy and pasting! See the amended code. thanks

Comment: OK... so I've just realised that the rendered html wraps the select in a div which is obviously why the select was not being returned! Thanks for the help @Johan - it made me see the error albeit a very simple one!